# How do i implement an upgrade plan for my android application?

Tags: android

As my question says I want to implement an upgrade plan for my Android app. I am new to Android development and would like some links, pointers & code examples of how to program the upgrading in the application. (I.E how does the android application handle the upgrade process)

Currently my app is version 1.0 and in a test stage. I am aware that when I release my app I will need to be able to upgrade as new functionality is added and reported bugs are fixed.
The app contains an Sqlite database that will also need upgrading during this process.

The app will not be released into the market place as the app is being created for CRM & ERP purposes.

Any links or tips would be greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

For the planning side of upgrades, if you're using Eclipse, you might consider using Mylyn Tasks to make a scheduled list of planned features & bug-fixes. You can link each task to your code, notes, and outside links, and share tasks across multiple developers on the project.

For the implementation of upgrades, make sure you're updating the version code (used by system) & version name (user-viewable) in the Android Manifest file. Each minor/major release **must** have its version code increased, otherwise the system won't know which version of the app has upgrade priority.

Also, if you're using a Sqlite database, the database has its own versioning scheme associated with structural changes (CREATE/DROP/ALTER TABLE). The database version doesn't have to correspond to the app version, but it also has to increase as changes are made. Check the docs on SQLOpenHelper and associated classes.

Finally, if you're using ProGuard or some other code obfuscator, maintain a copy of the mapping file generated during each app release. You'll need each version of that file to de-obfuscate any stack traces from earlier release versions.